Confusion about $\lim\sup$ and its definition as the greatest limit point
I posted a question a few days ago and the most voted answer uses $\lim \sup$, a concept I was not familiar with. I decided to jump ahead and read about $\lim\sup$ to understand the answer, but one thing has in particular confused me.
$\lim \sup$ is often said to be the greatest limit point of a sequence. Let's consider the sequence $s_n = \{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,...\}.$ As far as I understand, $\lim \sup{s_n} = 1$, but 1 doesn't seem to satisfy that for $L$ to be a limit point, there must be a subsequence of points different from L in $s_n$ that converges to $L$. But in this case, there is no such subsequence. What did I get wrong?

It's the greatest adherent point (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adherent_point).

A limit point of a sequence is the limit of any convergent subsequence. In this case, the relevant subsequence is $1,1,1...$.

@QiaochuYuan that makes sense now.... Thank you very much!

You're welcome. Frankly I don't understand why "limit point" is defined to be something different from an adherent point, it's a very strange convention. There's nothing wrong with isolated points.

@copper.hat Hi, I found a part of the link above that reads, "This definition (adherent point) differs from that of a limit point of a set, in that for a limit point it is required that every neighborhood of  contains at least one point of  different from ." Is it compatible with your statement?

@QiaochuYuan I guess I'm still too inexperienced for that discussion hehe, but I'll keep that in mind as I'm reading more about these concepts!

Definitions vary slightly, but there is a difference (apparently) between a limit point of a sequence (not a terminology I am familiar with) and a limit point of a set (which seems to be the source of your confusion). You need to focus on subsequences here.

@copper.hat I see your point! Thank you!
